# Unable to use DBD::Oracle from Apache/Mod_Perl

Tags: oracle, perl, apache, dbi, dbd

Env:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
Perl v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
64 bit Oracle client for 11.2
DBD::Oracle : Oracle Driver for DBI ; P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.64.tar.gz : /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DBD/Oracle.pm : Installed: 1.64 
/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oracle 48725761 Jun 10 17:41 /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
```

Startup.pl

```
use lib qw(/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib);
BEGIN {
    $ENV{ORACLE_HOME}     = '/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1';
    $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} = '/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib';
    $ENV{ORACLE_SID}      = 'MARS';
}
print STDERR "\nORACLE_HOME = " . $ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'} . "\n";
print STDERR "\nLD_LIBRARY_PATH = " . $ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'} . "\n";

use mod_perl2;
use Apache::DBI ();
use DBI ();
use DBD::Oracle;

BEGIN { use Data::Dumper; print STDERR Dumper(\@INC); }
print STDERR "ModPerl2 Startup.pl\n";
foreach ( keys %ENV ) {
    print STDERR "$_\t$ENV{$_}\n";
}
1;
```

Apache conf

```
PerlRequire /var/www/cgi-bin/startup.pl
SetEnv ORACLE_HOME "/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1"
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib"
```

Error:

```
Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.\n at /var/www/cgi-bin/startup.pl line 17\nCompilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/startup.pl line 17.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/startup.pl line 17.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 1.\n
```

**Startup.pl works when run from the command line, but fails to load through Apache**

Things already tried

- Setting env variables in Apache conf (shown above)
- Checking    file permisison for oracle libraries
- Printing env variables from    command line and comparing with the output when running from Apache    (after removing DBD::Oracle)
- Making sure all of Perl, Apache,    Oracle, DBD:Oracle are for 64 bit
- Adding /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib  to /etc/ld.so.conf  and running ldconf

Comment: Never got to the bottom of this problem. Built different version of Apache and ModPerl and tried various combinations of Oracle client until the problem went away.
Working combination: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: I hate it when the solution is inconclusive.  Still, thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from Apache being unable to find the Oracle installation.  Put your Oracle $PATH env vars in the bin/envvars file, like so:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
#
# envvars-std - default environment variables for apachectl
#
# This file is generated from envvars-std.in
#
ORACLE_HOME="/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH ORACLE_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DBD::Oracle` was built against 11.1 as evidenced by the error message, and it is looking for a specifically named/versioned .so file ("libclntsh.so.11.1").

Your runtime, however, is configured for 11.2, as evidenced by your paths, and does not supply that specifically named/versioned .so file.

Rebuild `DBD::Oracle` for your preferred runtime configuration and go from there.

Comment: This is where i left it "Never got to the bottom of this problem. Built different version of Apache and ModPerl and tried various combinations of Oracle client until the problem went away. Working combination: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.10.1"
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can well be a selinux issue. If your script runs well from shell but not from apache, try to disable selinux.

If it helps, you'd better CONFIGURE selinux instead of just disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error message on RHEL (5, 6 and 7). This is what finally fixed it for me:

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf
/sbin/ldconfig
service httpd stop; service httpd start
```